# Java Double Linked List Previous

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to create a double linked list and am having trouble with the removeLast method.

```
public class Node<E> {

E data;
public Node<E> next;
public Node<E> prev;

public Node(E d)
{
    data = d;
}

public E getData()
{
    return data;
}

}


public class TestList<E>  {

Node<E> head;
Node<E> tail;

public void addLast(E data)
{

    Node<E> newData = new Node<E>(data);

    if (head == null)
    {
        head = newData;
        tail = newData;
    }

    else
    {
        Node<E> current = head;

        while (current.next != null)
            current = current.next;

        current.next = newData;
        tail = current.next;

    }

}

public void removeLast()
{

    if (head == null)
        System.out.println("List is empty!");

    else
    {
        Node<E> current = tail;



    }


}
```

If for example I had a list of integers with the values 1, 3, 5 with 1 being the head and 5 being the tail, in my removeLast method I would like to know how I could make current.prev point to 3 and current.prev.prev point to 1 as right now it would just point to the next values which in this case would be null.

Comment: You should also focus on your addLast() method, which is wrong, and unnecessarily inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to modify both `addLast()` and `removeLest()` with check 3 different situations in both methods.

```
public final class TestList<E> {
    private Node<E> head;
    private Node<E> tail;

    public void addLast(E data) {
        Node<E> node = new Node<>(data);

        if (head == null)
            head = tail = node;
        else if (head == tail) {
            tail = node;
            head.next = tail;
            tail.prev = head;
        } else {
            tail.next = node;
            node.prev = tail;
            tail = node;
        }
    }

    public void removeLast() {
        if (tail == null)
            System.err.println("List is empty!");
        else if (head == tail)
            head = tail = null;
        else {
            Node<E> prev = tail.prev;
            tail.prev = null;
            tail = null;
            tail = prev;
            tail.next = null;
        }
    }

    private static final class Node<E> {
        E data;
        Node<E> next;
        Node<E> prev;

        public Node(E data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

- If the list is already empty, do nothing
- Or else, if head is the same as the tail (there is only one element in list), then clear the list
- Or else, make `tail.prev.next` point to `null`, and then make `tail = prev`

Like this:

```
public void removeLast() {
    if (head == null) {
        System.out.println("List is empty!");
        return;
    }

    if (head == tail) {
        head = tail = null;
        return;
    }

    Node<E> prev = tail.prev;
    prev.next = null;
    tail = prev;
}
```